# Spinner Unselectable

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a Spinner where a user selects an item from.  When it is submitted to the db, i then want that Spinner to be `unselectable`.  Just to display the item that was selected but not allowing the user to change it.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Spinner` class has a method for that:

```
 spinner.setEnabled(false);
```